# Is it safe to manage relationships by fetching related objects within subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, entity-relationship

Say I have an employee entity and a company entity in core data.

So employee and company are related to each other like this:

Employee <<---> Company

Now I am trying to right a manageRelationships method in each class, something like this:

```
@interface Employee : NSManagedObject
- (void)manageRelationships;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Company *company; // for relationship
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *companyId; // acts as foreign key 
@end

@implementation Employee
@dynamic company;
@dynamic companyId;
- (void)manageRelationships
{
   // prepare a predicate as @"companyId == %@",self.companyId

   // execute a fetch request against Company entity

   // map relationship using self.company = retrievedCompanyObject
}
```

Now I have few questions:

> 1. Is it safe to fire fetch request and map a relationship, as implemented above, within a subclass of NSManagedObject?
> 2. Is their any better way to achieve it? (Idea behind above approach is- I will be calling above method on each created managed object so
>      that it automatically manages and maps all associated relationships)

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do. But don't forget, Core Data provides you with an **object graph**, the database being only a secondary implementation detail. Thus, the whole notion of foreign keys is completely unnecessary, as the database layer is going to manage that for you.

But alas, I assume you just do not have the `Company` object around when you create the employee but are just given the company id. Of course you can override the `NSManagedObject` subclass, maybe best in the *setter* of the id property:

```
-(void)setCompanyId:(NSNumber*)newId {
   self.companyId = newId;
   if (!newId) { self.company = nil; }
   else {
      Company *myCompany = ... // fetch company
      self.company = myCompany;
   }
}
```

However, you can see how this is redundant. There is no need to keep the foreign key in your entity. You could retrieve it any time with

```
NSNumber *companyId = employee.company.id;
```

So maybe it is better to simply add a method to your `Employee` class that conveniently adds a company:

```
-(void)addCompanyWithId:(NSNumber*)companyID {
   if (!companyID) { self.company = nil; }
   else {
      Company *employer = ...// fetch company
      self.company = employer ? employer : nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: hey.. thnx for the useful answer :-)